# Cannot find Android SDK Manager settings on MAC OS

Tags: android, macos, android-sdk-tools

I have been switching my working env to MAC OS recently.

However, I found that I cannot find the "Settings" of Android SDK Manager on MAC OS.

When the Android SDK Manager opened, there is no button/tab can be clicked to launch the settings panel like it on Windows.

I want to set the "force http" / "proxy" options.

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is there in the Preferences. From the menu bar, go to Android SDK Manager -> Preferences menu.

**Edit:** If you do not see the *Android SDK Manager* menu after opening the SDK manager, try to switch back to the application using the Command + Tab key combinations.

[image: Preferences Menu]

Comment: I am using this ADT bundle, I see different from what you have just post. My menu bar is  | APPLE LOG | ADT | File | Edit ... And after I opened the SDK manager, the menu bar is only APPLE LOGO | ADT and cannot be clicked.

Comment: Yes I opened the manager, and the menu bar is APPLE | ADT, and not click-able

Comment: You can open the Android SDK manager directly from the Finder (or command line) by opening the `android` application from adt-bundle-xxxx/sdk/tools folder.

Comment: After opening the SDK manager, try to switch back to the application using the Command + Tab key combinations.

Comment: Welcome to the world of OSX quirkiness.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Mac, you will have to do Cmd+Tab a few times for the menu to show up on top.

At first, you will see the menu of the parent app, say the Terminal, or IntelliJ, only after a bit of switching back and forth the menu finally is displayed.

[image]